# Tricky filtering data

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, dataverse

In a Power App, I'm looking to filter a gallery with Dataverse table data by a Location column. Examples of Locations are as follows: L.1.1.1A, L.2.5.3B, L.9.1.12C, L.10.3.2A

I want to filter where the Location begins where the second number (the character after the second period) is a 1 or a 2. If the character I was looking at was at the beginning or the end, I know I could use StartsWith or EndsWith (as shown below), but I don't know how I can solve for this situation where the value is in the middle of the string.

```
Filter('DataTable',Or(StartsWith(Location,"L.1"),StartsWith(Location,"L.2")))
```

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-find

First, find the position of the second period. Let’s say we name this PosDot2

Now you can take a substring by using for example:

```
Right( Len( Location.Data) - PosDot2 )
```

EDIT:

In order to explain a bit more: L.1.2.3A is your example.

With the function 'find', you can find your period.

```
Find(
  ".",
  YourLocation
)
```

This gives the first location, which we will name P1.
P2 can be found via:

```
Find(
  ".",
  YourLocation,
  P1 + 1
```

)

Via Mid, you can retrieve everything between the first and second period via:

```
Mid(
  YourLocation,
  P1 + 1,
  P2 - P1 - 1
)
```

This gives the subsection.

[A demo](https://github.com/Ionavoss/PowerApps/blob/main/Regex/SubstringsInPowerApps.msapp) can be found here on my Github repo, so you can get a feeling of what's happening

Comment: I'm sorry. Can you guide me through this a little more for me? I don't understand how to name the position of the second period, so the rest of it isn't making sense to me either.

Comment: I edited my first answer with some more details and a link to a demo for you

Comment: That helps and makes sense to me. But how can I incorporate that into my filter formula?

Comment: AddColumns. You can add a column to your data that takes the value you want. And that column you can filter.